# summing terms to the cardinality all possible subsets of a given set

Tags: combinatorics, summation, cardinals

I am  facing the problem of computing the sum
$$\sum_{L\subset S}(-1)^{|S|-|L|},$$
where $|S|$ denotes the cardinality of a set $S$ is finite and $L$ is a proper subset of $S$.
Thank you!

Comment: Hint: add different steps to your sum. First sum over all possible cardinal of k=|S| then sum over all sets of cardinal $k$. Do the same for $L$ of course and then binomial coefficients will appear and you will be able to apply the binomial formula after this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the cardinallity of $\{L\subset S: |L| = j\}$ is $\binom{|S|}{j}$,
we have: $$\sum_{L\subsetneq S}(-1)^{|S|-|L|} = \sum_{j=0}^{|S|-1}\sum_{L\subset S,\\|L|=j}(-1)^{|S|-|L|} = \\ = \sum_{j=0}^{|S| - 1}\binom{|S|}{j}(-1)^{|S|-j} $$

Does this look familiar?

Comment: Yes, binomial formula! What about the final exponent of (-1)? It should be |S|+1 right? Because it would be $(-1)^{|S|} -1=(-1)^{|S|+1}$

Comment: @Jo R I'd actuall go by $\sum_{L\subsetneq S}(-1)^{|S|-|L|} = \sum_{L\subseteq S}(-1)^{|S|-|L|} - S\cdot (-1)^{|S|}$

Comment: I mean, if I had $j=|S|$, I would add $\binom{|S|}{|S|}(-1)^{|S|-|S|}=+1$, so I take away this term from binomial formula with total exponent |S|.

Comment: @Jo R You are correct, and my last comment is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Finding a subset of $|S|$ of cardinality $|L|$ is the same as finding a subset of cardinality $|S|-|L|$ so let us rewrite the sum as
$$\sum_{L\subset S}(-1)^{|L|}.$$
Now, there is exactly ${|S|}\choose{|L|}$ subset of size $|L|$ in $S$. So the sum becomes
$$\sum_{|L|=0}^{|S|-1}{{|S|}\choose{|L|}}(-1)^{|L|} = (-1)^{|S|}$$
using Newton's binomial formula.